# facing issues while connecting to HANA

Tags: azure, odbc, hana, azure-data-factory

I'm using a copy activity to get data from SAP HANA as source and ADLS as sink and an Azure self-IR, the test connection is ok but when I execute the pipeline I got the error below. Has someone faced a similar error?

I would really appreciate your help to guide me, there's no error reported in Microsoft.

> "Code": 9603,
> "Message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToConnectOdbcSource,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;-10757 Secure store error: d:\701\w\7hhepnmjzk\src\interfaces\securestore\impl\securestore.cpp:190 - (91003) Invalid secure store key\r\nERROR [HY000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;-10757 Secure store error: d:\701\w\7hhepnmjzk\src\interfaces\securestore\impl\securestore.cpp:190 - (91003) Invalid secure store key,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapHanaConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;-10757 Secure store error: d:\701\w\7hhepnmjzk\src\interfaces\securestore\impl\securestore.cpp:190 - (91003) Invalid secure store key\r\nERROR [HY000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;-10757 Secure store error: d:\701\w\7hhepnmjzk\src\interfaces\securestore\impl\securestore.cpp:190 - (91003) Invalid secure store key,Source=,'",

Answer (score 0):

> ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToConnectOdbcSource,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;-10757 Secure store error: d:\701\w\7hhepnmjzk\src\interfaces\securestore\impl\securestore.cpp:190 - (91003) Invalid secure store key\r\nERROR [HY000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC]

By looking at error message and error code it seems to error is related to the **SAP HANA ODBC driver**

To utilize SAP HANA Connector, you have to complete prerequisites mentioned in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-hana?tabs=data-factory):

- Set up a Self-hosted Integration Runtime.
- On the Integration Runtime computer, install the **SAP HANA ODBC driver.** to use SAP HANA from computer.

> You can download the SAP HANA ODBC driver from the [SAP Software Download Center](https://support.sap.com/swdc). Search with the keyword SAP HANA CLIENT for Windows.

Also see required linked service properties from document.

[image]

Also see this [video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/sap-on-azure-training-videos/integrating-your-sap-data-by-using-azure-data-factory-adf) of ADF and SAP HANA connection for more information.

Comment: Actually when I execute the hardcoded copy activity separately works fine and ingest the data but, when I try to use the copy activity inside my pipelines and I pass the right parameters it fails to get the data. I'll check trough the documentation.